# How to send the variable to different php while using uplodify

Tags: php, jquery, uploadify

I want to integrate the [uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) to my legacy application.

I am not able to find the way to send some variable (name of file) to my current legacy file.
(That file has `database` code to store the file along with other form parameter in common table).

Could you please tell me how can I send the name of files which are being uploaded by `uplodify` to my legacy php file.

Comment: Can you add some example code? How does your other php file except to receive this variable?

Comment: My old file is accepting the name of files in old school way if ($_FILES['picture1']['name']) {
$filename = $_FILES['picture1']['name'];

Comment: I just want to keep the code of uplodify.php separate than my old legacy file. Otherwise I have to rewrite my legacy file.

Comment: Code or it didn't happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In uploadify, once you have the filename of the uploaded file, you can call your old code using:

```
file_get_contents("http://yoursite.com/legacy.php?filename=" . urlencode($filename));
```

And then in legacy.php:

```
if($_FILES['picture1']['name']){
    $filename = $_FILES['picture1']['name'];
}else if(isset($_GET['filename'])){
    $filename = $_GET['filename'];
}
```

It would be a good idea to do a sanity check and make sure that `$_GET['filename']` is located in a directory where you're expecting uploaded files, and isn't something like `"/etc/shadow"`, since legacy.php is likely accessible to the outside web.

This isn't the best or most secure way to accomplish what you want, but it's probably the quickest and simplest.